# Replace U.FL connecter with a wire antenna

Tags: antenna, xbee

I have an XBee module with a U.FL. connecter. Is it possible to solder an appropriate wire antenna to this module (without buying a new module with a wire antenna)? Since U.FL. has 2 connections and wire antenna needs just one, how do I do it? (My knowledge on antennas are low.)

Comment: A link to the module would be useful along with some extra words about operating frequency, connecter name in the data in the link etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is usually a pretty easy task.

Likely, you have an XBee that looks something like this (at least in antenna configuration):

[image]

Now, what you really want is this (again, just looking at antenna configuration):

[image]

So, what you need to do should be pretty clear from here. De-solder the U.F.L. connector, then solder a short wire into the little hole on the top right corner of the old U.F.L connector location (not the big hole with a big pad around it, but the one above that). The wire length depends on what frequency your XBee runs at - for 2.4 GHz it's roughly 31mm for bare copper, and 25 for an insulated wire (for a quarter wave antenna, which is what they normally ship with).

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to Zplizzi's solution would be to use a piece of coax cable with the U.FL connector, then strip the shielding all the way. The length should be roughly 8cm.
This way you don't have to de-solder the connector.